# How to create recurring profile using credit card on payflow hosted checkout page

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payflowpro

Is it possible to create recurring profile using credit card on payflow hosted checkout page? If yes give me please link to instructions how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

[Recurring Billing Service User’s Guide](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PayflowPro_RecurringBilling_Guide.pdf)

Chapter 2 is Using the SDK to Perform Recurring Tasks

Comment: I don't see there information about creating recurring profiles on hosted page. I know about the possibility of creating such profiles through api, but the client wants that his customers enter credit card sensitive information on Paypal site for safety. So I asking is that possible or I can only create such profiles via manager.paypal.com and api?